# Joda.Time DateTimeFormat returns: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format is malformed

Tags: scala, jodatime

I am converting some date formats from `"ddMMMyyyy"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. I have written the code below:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def dateFormatter(date: String, inpuFormat: String, outputFormat: String): String = {
    var returnDate: String = ""
    val inputDateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(inpuFormat)
    val outputDateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(outputFormat)

    Try {
      if (date != null && date.trim != "") {
        val parsedDate = DateTime.parse(date.trim(), inputDateFormat)
        returnDate = outputDateFormat.print(parsedDate)
      } else { returnDate = null }
    } match {
      case Success(_) => { returnDate }
      case Failure(e) => {
        println("exception!" + e)
        date
      }
    }
  }
```

I am using scala 2.12

If I pass as input:

```
"09September2032"
```

Then I get

```
"2032-09-09"
```

However if I pass

```
"09sep2032"
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "09sep2032" is malformed at "sep2032"
```

What is wrong with the provided pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It seems for September, we need to pass 4 characters **Sept**

```
  println(dateFormatter("09Jan2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Feb2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Mar2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Apr2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09May2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Jun2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Jul2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Aug2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Sept2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Oct2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Nov2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  println(dateFormatter("09Dec2032", "ddMMMyyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Would output:

```
2032-01-09
2032-02-09
2032-03-09
2032-04-09
2032-05-09
2032-06-09
2032-07-09
2032-08-09
2032-09-09
2032-10-09
2032-11-09
2032-12-09
```